# ssh SendEnv from windows to linux server using cygwin

Tags: windows, ssh, opensuse, environment-variables, bashrc

I am doing ssh to a Open SUSE linux server from windows cygwin. I am trying to send one of my local environment variable through the ssh command so that I can load some specific .bashrc file right after logging in. Here is what I have tried with.

Windows Machine has this env variable

```
IDENTITY=samiron
echo %IDENTITY%
   samiron
```

In linux machine I have

```
vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
AcceptEnv IDENTITY
```

In `/home/user/.bashrc` I have written something like

```
export ME=$IDENTITY
```

My plan is to have a file like `.bashrc.samiron` and do `source  ~/.bashrc.$ME` from `.bashrc` file.

However, I am doing ssh like below and expecting the variable `$ME` to contain `"samiron"`

```
ssh -o SendEnv=IDENTITY user@server.com
```

But after logging

```
user@server:~> echo $ME
```

Its shows nothing. Anyone can suggest me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two conditions should be met before it can work as expected:

1. Your ssh server has to be configured to accept forwarding of variables from local client's environment. As it may be a security risk to allow such behavior it is usually disabled by default. You can enable it by specifying **"AcceptEnv"** directive in your ssh server configuration. So put something like this to **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** file and **reload** the ssh server service (variable names can contain wildcards, you can specify multiple variables separated by whitespaces, details in **man sshd_config**)

   AcceptEnv VARIABLE_NAME
2. This feature works for ssh protocol of **version 2** only. This is fulfilled almost in all modern Linux distribution by default if it wasn't changed (**"Protocol"** directive).

Answer (score 1):

Oh I was missing the part of restarting the sshd server.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

solved my problem